# Prevent Application Shutdown iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm building a little dialing program for my kids so that only 4 "safe" numbers are available for them to dial. I'd like to start the app, hand them the phone and have the app be the only thing running until they come back home.

Is there a way to keep the application running and prevent the iPhone from shutting down the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone SDK does not allow this. Any application can be exited when the user presses the home button. In fact if your program takes too long to exit (e.g. infinite loop) it will forcefully close your application.

If you must have this behavior, your best bet would be to jailbreak the phone in which case anything could pretty much be done.

Comment: Bummer...that's what I figured but hoped there was a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Not with Apple's SDK, no.